# Load Image from URL in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, base64, png

I'm trying to load an image from the following url: 
https://fangkarte.de:8080/fangfisch/file/files/592036af55dfffca0155e01fe10002f7

In Chrome/IE the image will be displayed without problems. When I try to load the image on Android I am not able to store the image as an PNG file. Everytime the image will be saved as a textfile which contains the image as base64 String.

Also I tried the following code but the decodedByte is null:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can show my image from the url as an bitmap or which I prefer to store the image on the device as an png?

Comment: use it for load img http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion but unfortunatelly picasso does not work in this particular case. I have tried it

Comment: What is size of decodedString ?

Comment: `Everytime the image will be saved as a textfile ` You are not showing how you did that. And you did not tell what this text file contains. But byte[] decodedString should contain the png. So save byte[] decodedString  to file to have a .png file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Universal Image Loder to upload image from Url
Download universal image loder and add to your lib folder and

Implement the below code where you want to load image

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.noimage)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.icon3)
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loading).build();

imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageview, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

For handling images, Use Picasso , Glide , Universal image loader, Volley or Fresco

Eg, in picasso, you will be able to load images, store them in memory cache and handle cancellations in listviews/recyclerviews etc...

Picasso.with(context).load("https://fangkarte.de:8080/fangfisch/file/files/592036af55dfffca0155e01fe10002f7").placeholder("someimagetillyourimagedownloads).into(R.id.yourimageview);

Picasso: https://github.com/square/picasso

Glide: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Fresco: https://github.com/facebook/fresco ( I use this after extensively testing all 3 except volley )

UIL: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Similar things can be done using all the above libraries.

I highly recommend not trying to handle images on your own. It can turn into quite a mess if you are a novice android dev.

Answer (score 0):

The image you download is much to big ((860.000 bytes)) to make a Bitmap out of it. So BitmapFactory will return null.

Scale image down before use.